# Reliable way to run a task right before rAF in each frame

Tags: javascript, browser, requestanimationframe

I stumped upon an [article - requestAnimationFrame Scheduling For Nerds](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/requestanimationframe-scheduling-for-nerds-9c57f7438ef4) posted by Paul Irish.

I read it through then coming up with a question that **is there any way we can schedule a task which run just right before rAF in each frame (see enclosed picture) ?**

[image: Life of a frame]

Comment: And why would you need that?

Comment: I need to delay DOM read inside requestAnimationFrame callback until next frame to avoid reflow

Comment: Yes, the requirement is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all Chrome and Firefox run rAF before layout and paint that paul explained in his article. [Safari and IE](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2569)  have different behavior, [Edge is fixing](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/973495246091845634?lang=en);

Now lets back to your question; consider there is way to run a little peace of JS (My Task) right before rAF callback in every frame. lets assume that "My Task" execution takes ~4ms and your rAF callback takes ~5ms to complete in every frame. this would be total of ~9ms of JS execution. so what is the point here? we could just run everything inside that rAF callback in ~9ms, In other words that is equivalent to extend the length of rAF execution:

total JS execution before the frame = My Task code execution + regular rAF codes execution

We can do all the Frame Critical JS executions inside the rAF itself; there is no point to separate JS execution into two parts ( My Task + rAF ) since you don't have more than [~10ms to execute](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering#60fps_and_device_refresh_rates) rAF (JS code) before Layout and Paint, and if we exceed that fps drops and we will see janks;

TL:DR; There is no way other than rAF callback to execute js in that critical time yet :)